# Is there a correct way to deploy a Ruby/Gtk3 App in Windows?

Tags: ruby, gtk3, ocra

I need a small application made for windows (xp and later) desktops, with a system tray icon that stays there.  I want to make it in Ruby (somehow, after i started using Ruby, i can't stay focused when i try to use something else, either .net or Java based languages seem weird and unreadable), so i tried qtbindings (4.8 Qt), JRuby and now Gtk.  Gtk seems the way to do it, documentation is good, it's being developed very actively, and everything works in windows as intended (i couldn't get jruby 9000 to work, and qtbindings is a bit outdated, with no documentation at all).

The problem is this: when i use [ocra](https://github.com/larsch/ocra) to make the exe, it packages all the dependencies of my app (ruby - Gtk), creating either a zipped exe of 95MB that takes 35 seconds to boot (as it has to unzip it before starting the actual app), or a 495MB file unzipped exe (using the --no-lzma option), that still takes some time to load (24 seconds), but this size is not acceptable, we are talking about a Hello World app here of less than a KB.

Your take on this?  Can i have a user download gtk and not include it in the exe? Or can i make an installer (i saw InnoSetup option in ocra github) that does the needed installations?

Comment: Just a suggestion: You could try Python, with TkInter for the graphics part. Python is somewhat similar to Ruby and its object orientation, and Tkinter is lighter than the entire gtk environment.

Comment: I'm going to take a look on TkInter but i would still want a ruby solution if there is one to begin with.